# Access class instance "name" dynamically in Python

Tags: python

In plain english:  I am creating class instances dynamically in a for loop, the class then defines a few attributes for the instance.  I need to later be able to look up those values in another for loop.

Sample code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, attr):
        self.name=name
        self.attr=attr

names=("a1", "a2", "a3")
x=10
for name in names:
    name=A(name, x)
    x += 1
...
...
...
for name in names:
    print name.attr
```

How can I create an identifier for these instances so they can be accessed later on by "name"?

I've figured a way to get this by associating "name" with the memory location:

```
class A:
    instances=[]
    names=[]
    def __init__(self, name, attr):
        self.name=name
        self.attr=attr
        A.instances.append(self)
        A.names.append(name)

names=("a1", "a2", "a3")
x=10
for name in names:
    name=A(name, x)
    x += 1
...
...
...
for name in names:
    index=A.names.index(name)
    print "name:  " + name
    print "att:  " + str(A.instances[index].att)
```

This has had me scouring the web for 2 days now, and I have not been able to find an answer.  Maybe I don't know how to ask the question properly, or maybe it can't be done (as many other posts seemed to be suggesting).

Now this 2nd example works, and for now I will use it.  I'm just thinking there has to be an easier way than creating your own makeshift dictionary of index numbers and I'm hoping I didn't waste 2 days looking for an answer that doesn't exist.  Anyone have anything?

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Update:  A coworker just showed me what he thinks is the simplest way and that is to make an actual dictionary of class instances using the instance "name" as the key.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes keeping it simple is best. Having a dict that stores your instances with their names as the keys would be both straightforward and fairly simple to implement.

```
class A:
    instances={}
    def __init__(self, name, attr):
        self.name=name
        self.attr=attr
        A.instances[name] = self
```

and then to get the proper instance, just...

```
instance = A.instances[name]
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to put the instance dict inside the class. Just create a dict, `inst` in the local scope:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, attr):
        self.name=name
        self.attr=attr

inst={}
names=("a1", "a2", "a3")
x=10
for name in names:
    inst[name]=A(name, x)
    x += 1
```

Then, whenever you want to access a certain instance by name, just use `inst[name]`:

```
for name in names:
    print inst[name].attr
```

Comment: Why *not* put the dict inside the class? It makes far more sense organization-wise to have it there if it's always going to be utilized.

Comment: What happens if the OP has many classes with named instances, ('a1','a2','b1','b2')?
Does he really want to access them with `A.instances['a1']` and `B.instances['b1']`?
Having to select both the right class and the right name is unnecessary and redundant. The names can and should be unique. So they should be accessible from a common dict defined outside of any class.

As I see it, the question the OP is asking is how to deal with dynamically named *variables*, and has nothing in particular to do with the fact that the values of those variables happen to be instances of a class.

Comment: @~unutbu, that all depends entirely on the problem at hand. It may be that the code _wants_ A and B names to be in separate namespaces. And even in the case of a shared namespace, it would make more sense for all such types to inherit from some common NamedObject type, that implements everything. One should avoid injecting stuff into outer namespaces where practicable.

Comment: @Marcelo, I agree that there are problems where storing a collection of
instances may be useful (logging handlers come to mind). But even in that
example, the class that stores the instances is a Manager class
(c.f. /usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py) which is distinct from the class
generating the instances.  If the OP's problem is simple, then I'd suggest, as
above, using a local dict. If the management of the named instances is
complicated, then I'd suggest using a Manager class.

Comment: To do anything useful, the base class `A` must have duties other
than managing its instances. `A` should focus on fulfilling that
duty. By making `A` also its own manager, you are giving `A` two
duties, which makes the `A` class less flexible. I can't think of
any situation where this is desireable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dictionary approach should work well, and can be dovetailed into the class itself.

```
class A:
    _instances = {}

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name):
        return A._instances[name]

    def __init__(self, name, attr):
        self.name=name
        self.attr=attr
        A._instances[name] = self

a = A('foo', 10)
aa = A.get('foo')
```

If you want to play around with `__new__`, you can even make this transparent:

```
a = A('foo', 10)
aa = A('foo') # 'a' and 'aa' refer to the same instance.
```

This is a bit complicated, so I'll leave it to you to research (and of course ask another question on SO if you get stuck).