# Python OOP select instance dynamically

Tags: python, python-class

I have two instances of Python class (i simplified logic to make it shorter)

```
class First:
    def first_p(self):
        print('test')

    
first_instance = First()
second_instance = First()
```

Now i need select which one instance to use (i could do it by repeat code in if/else)

```
if x:
   second.first_p()
else:
   first.first_p()
```

But i wander how i can do it like this (it's not working)

```
'{}'.first_p().format(second)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access class instance "name" dynamically in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733580/access-class-instance-name-dynamically-in-python)

Comment: @Machina OP is trying to choose which instance dynamically - not the property AFAIU.

Comment: The *correct* approach here is to create *an explicit mapping, i.e. a `dict` that maps the strings to the desired objects*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to achieve something like this:

```py
class First:
    def first_p(self):
        return 'test' 


first_instance = First()
second_instance = First()

print(f"{ (first_instance if x else second_instance).first_p() }")
```

because "`'{}'.first_p().format(second)`" doesn't make any sense (since you're calling `first_p` as if it's a method in `Str`)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question can be simplified into "How could I access a variable base on the string?"

It is actually possible, depends on the scope:

```
# global scope
instance = globals()[second]
instance.first_p()
```

Ref: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/globals

```
# local scope, such as inside a function
instance = locals()[second]
instance.first_p()
```

Ref: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/locals

Answer (score 1):

```
'{}'.format(second_instance.p() if x else first_instance.p())
```